# Set output speaker for openTok?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avaudiosession, opentok

I try to make an audio/video call with `openTok` with the possibility to change de output speaker. I want to be set on ear speaker for default and i use that code.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]  overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
self.audioSpeakerButton.selected =true;
```

First time i play a ringtone with `AVAudioPlayer` with code below:

```
audioPLayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:pewPewURL fileTypeHint:@"mp3" error:nil];
audioPLayer.numberOfLoops=-1;
[audioPLayer prepareToPlay];
[audioPLayer play];
```

The sound comes from ear speaker which is good. 
After when the second user is connected i stop the `audioPlayer` but the sound it is comes from loudspeaker which is bad.

```
- (void)subscriberDidConnectToStream:(OTSubscriberKit *)subscriber
{
    [audioPLayer pause];
    [audioPLayer stop];
    audioPLayer = nil;
 }
```

I use that button action for change output speaker but nothing is changed.

```
-(void)audioSpeakerButtonAction{
    if (![self.audioSpeakerButton isSelected]) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]  overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
        self.audioSpeakerButton.selected = YES;
    } else {
        NSError *error = nil;overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
        self.audioSpeakerButton.selected = NO;
    }
}


I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Hi. did you got any perfect solution?

Comment: Yeah. you have same problem?

Comment: Yes. Can you please explain ho to do?.
I have doing some codes and it works for first call and after that it didn't work for next call.

Comment: I created a custom class and set it like audio device : `OTDefaultAudioDeviceWithVolumeControl* audioDevice =
    [OTDefaultAudioDeviceWithVolumeControl sharedInstance];
    
    [OTAudioDeviceManager setAudioDevice:audioDevice];`

Comment: Can we discuss at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130176/room-for-mehul-sojitra-and-gaby-fitcal?

Comment: If you guys found solution please post answer here so that it can helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This has been resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645017/how-to-select-audiooutput-with-opentok

Comment: @GabyFitcal... I didn't found any solution yet. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: @Aayushi it was very long time ago. I'm not using OpenTok anymore and I'm not updated with last changes of the framework. I'm sorry but I can't help you