# How to select audioOutput with OpenTok

Tags: webrtc, opentok

I am building a simple **WebRTC** app with **OpenTok**.
I need to be able to select camera, audio input and audio output.
Currently that doesn't seem easily possible.

See [opentok-hardware-setup](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-hardware-setup.js)

> https://github.com/opentok/opentok-hardware-setup.js/issues/18

I am loading **OpenTok** in my `index.html` file
and `opentok-hardware-setup.js`.

All looks great and I can select microphone and camera BUT not the speaker out aka `audiooutput`.

```
<script src="https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js"></script>
```

From the console, I tried

```
OT.getDevices((err, devices) => { console.debug(devices)});
```

and observed that you can't get the `audioOutput`

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {deviceId: "default", label: "Default - Built-in Microphone", kind: "audioInput"}
1: {deviceId: "b183634b059298f3692aa7e5871e6a463127701e21e320742c48bda99acdf925", label: "Built-in Microphone", kind: "audioInput"}
2: {deviceId: "4b441035a4db3c858c65c30eabe043ae1967407b3cc934ccfb332f0f6e33a029", label: "Built-in Output", kind: "audioInput"}
3: {deviceId: "05415e116b36584f848faeef039cd06e5290dde2e55db6895c19c8be3b880d91", label: "FaceTime HD Camera", kind: "videoInput"}
length
:4 __proto__:Array(0)
```

whereas you can get them using `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`

[image]

Any pointers?

Comment: A recent answer to the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48917490/5433407

Comment: thx. Interesting that this wasn't implemented in `OT.getDevices()` yet. I will have to use WebRTC native API

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disclosure, I'm an employee at TokBox :). OpenTok does not currently provide a way to specify the audio output device. This is still an experimental API and only works in Chrome. When the API is standardised and has wider browser support we will make it easier.

In the meantime, it's pretty easy to do this using native WebRTC. There is a good sample for this at https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/multi/ the source code can be found at https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/devices/multi/js/main.js

In summary you use the `enumerateDevices` method as you found. Then you use the `setSinkId()` method on the video element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId

You can get access to the `videoElement` by listening to the `videoElementCreated` event on the subscriber like so:

```
subscriber.on('videoElementCreated', (event) => {
  if (typeof event.element.sinkId !== 'undefined') {
    event.element.setSinkId(deviceId)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('successfully set the audio output device');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('Failed to set the audio output device ', err);
    });
  } else {
    console.warn('device does not support setting the audio output');
  }
});
```

Comment: I was trying to achieve that with `@opentok/client@2.15.10` but it looks like for Safari and Chrome >= 71 there is a separate audio element created and there is no access to it from `videoElementCreated` event.

Answer (score 2):

So,
The answer gave by @Adam Ullman is not valid anymore since there is a separate audio element created alongside the video element preventing us to use the `setSinkId` method of the video element.

I found a solution consisting in finding the audio element from the video one and using its own `setSinkId`.
Code:

```
  const subscriber_videoElementCreated = async event => {
    const videoElem = event.element;
    const audioElem = Array.from(videoElem.parentNode.childNodes).find(child => child.tagName === 'AUDIO');
    if (typeof audioElem.sinkId !== 'undefined') {
      try {
        await audioElem.setSinkId(deviceId);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Could not update speaker ', err);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Sorry, we are aware of this issue and actually the upcoming 2.16.0 will put the implementation back to having just one Video Element instead of 2 separate elements. I hope this doesn't cause too much trouble.

Comment: Now v2.16.0 is out and we are back to having one video element

Answer (score 2):

OpenTok (now Vonage) now provides an API for doing exactly this in 2.22.
It is not supported on all browsers (Safari), but for browsers which support setSinkID, there is now a uniform API which wraps the functionality handily.

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/audio-video/js/#setAudioOutput